# create an attribute and populate it with node value xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to do this using xslt, new to this and struggling.

```
<xsl:template match="h1"> 
<h1 title=""> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
</h1> 
</xsl:template>
```

**Example XML**

```
<h1>This is the inner text <para>some other text</para>
</h1>
```

**Desired output**

```
  <h1 title="This is the inner text"><para>some other text</para>
</h1>
```

Comment: Where is the XSLT you have so far?

Comment: <xsl:template match="h1">
   <h1 title="">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </h1>
</xsl:template>

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following should work. You can remove your template for `h1` as it would be superfluous:

```
<xsl:template match="h1/node()[1][self::text()]">
  <xsl:attribute name="title">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

This template matches a text node when it is the first child node of an `h1`, and substitutes it with a `title` attribute whose value is that of the text node.